# Como verificar um radio button

Tags: php, javascript

Minha duvida é como verificar se um **radio button** foi selecionado!

Eu tenho um **while** que conforme for encontrando valores dentro de uma **tabela**, ele vai adicionando os **radios buttons**. Assim, quando o **radio** for selecionado e for clicado no **"IR"** ele vai chamar a outra pag. passando os valores do radio. Mas sempre tem a opção de não ter selecionado nada ... Como deveria fazer para realizar essa verificação?

Comment: Se nada for selecionado, o value do radio vai ser nulo.

Comment: Sim disso eu tenho noção! Mas como eu incluo um radio a cada valor encontrado na tabela, ele sempre vai ser o mesmo nome, e o valor aparece como undefinid!

Comment: faça um if para verificar se o value é diferente de undefined

Comment: Sim isso mesmo @Bacco!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo simples de como ler o *Radio Button* em PHP.

HTML:

```
<form action="recebe.php">
   <input type="radio" name="teste" value="um">Um<br>
   <input type="radio" name="teste" value="dois">Dois<br>
   <input type="radio" name="teste" value="três">Três<br>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$escolha = @$_POST['teste']; // Usado @, já que vai ser testado em seguida.

if isempty( $escolha ) $pagina='URL da pagina padrao...';
else if $escolha == 'um' $pagina= 'URL da pagina um';
else if $escolha == 'dois' $pagina= 'URL da pagina dois';
else if $escolha == 'tres' $pagina= 'URL da pagina tres';
else $pagina = 'URL da pagina padrao, ou de erro';

...
```

Lembrando que você pode forçar um dos inputs a ter o valor pré-selecionado usando `checked`, mas deve verificar o caso de estar nulo mesmo assim:

```
   <input type="radio" name="teste" value="um" checked />Um<br>
   //                                             ^^^
```

Comment: Isso ajudou muito @ Bacco. Obrigado por compartilhar!!

Comment: @Felipe conseguiu testar? Se estiver tudo ok, me avise, pois aí nem mexo mais. Estava tentando testar aqui, mas meu link está péssimo (vários erros de conexao, o cabo deve ter zoado)

Comment: Sim ajudou perfeitamente @Bacco! O problema que eu estava tendo em verificar se estava ou não selecionado, foi resolvido!

Comment: Não é recomendado fazer a supressão de erros `$escolha = @$_POST['teste'];` faça assim `$escolha = (isset($_POST['teste']) ? $_POST['teste'] : NULL);`
e
`if( is_null($escolha ))...`

Comment: @Carlos Entendo que você está querendo ajudar, mas leia o comment que eu pus imediatamente após a supressão, na mesma linha. O valor já é testado na linha seguinte, portanto sua sugestão é redundante. Cuidado com as tais "boas práticas" (o tal do "não é recomendado"), pois sem saber o que está fazendo, você no mínimo vai escrever código à toa e/ou ineficiente (tanto que, provavelmente você não conseguiria explicar qual a vantagem obtida com a sua sugestão).

Comment: Certo @Bacco, não quis dizer que sua resposta não funcionou nem nada do tipo. Como o Stackoverflow mesmo diz:

A aceitação não significa que seja a melhor resposta, apenas significa que foi útil para a pessoa que perguntou.

Só estava complementando, dizendo que em boas práticas de programação a supressão de erros é só pra quando não existe uma alternativa melhor. Ou seja o uso de `isset` e `is_null` é muito mais recomendado no meio do que o uso de `@` em operações. Abraços.

Comment: @Carlos eu sei disto que você está dizendo, mas só quero deixar claro que a supressão neste caso é perfeitamente válida, pois o valor será testado na linha seguinte. Sua proposta simplesmente faz mais testes desnecessariamente, com zero de benefício. Não estou preocupado em ganhar uma disputa de argumentos, apenas quis esclarecer que "boas práticas" não servem pra nada se usadas cegamente, e você pode se beneficiar entendendo quando é bom e quando não é. De qq forma, como já disse, entendo que vc quer ajudar, e agradeço, porém isto será lido por muitas pessoas, então prefiro "desmistificar".